# React HOC pattern - dealing with async methods

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs

I want to create HOC container which changes its state asynchronously.

It will be used by two components.

What is the best way for these components to subscribe to success/failure of HOC async methods and update their internal state accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

REDUX can also be used.

1. your compoents must be pure  and reusable do not tie them to state
   cause app will just waste system resources doing unnessary re
   render. The use of state should be as limited as it can get. When
   you use state, you run the risk of introducing a number of
   (sometimes subtle) errors in the behaviour and rendering of your
   components. If you decide to use properties to define your initial
   state; your properties might change, leaving your initial state
   calculations based on stale data. You also introduce tight coupling
   between the properties that need to be defined, and the internal
   state of the component.
2. A general rule is not to use state for static components. If you
   component does not need to change, based on external factors, then
   do not use state. It’s better to calculate rendered values in the
   render() method. link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymJOm5jY1tQ.

   https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e#.h3ioly71l

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export const fetchResource = msg => WrappedComponent =>
  class extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        resource: null,
        msg: null
      };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({msg})
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/miketembos/repos')
        .then((response)=>{
          console.log(response);
          if(response.status===200){
            return response.data;
          } else {
            throw new Error("Server response wasn't ok");
          }

        })
        .then((responseData)=>{
          this.setState({resource:responseData});
        }).catch((error)=>{
          this.props.history.pushState(null, '/error');
        });
    }

    render(){
      const {resource} = this.state
      //check if the resource is valid eg not empty or null
      if(!resource){return <div>Loading...... or show any othe component you want load.....</div>}
      return <Post {...this.props} {...resource } />
    }
  }
```

[image: high order component react with async call]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, post the code instead.

Comment: React / Facebook's original reference pattern for this, Flux, is a good starting place as well.  Redux is one of many *ux patterns derived from it. https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html